# UK Tourist Visa for a couple

Tags: visas, uk

We are applying for a tourist visa to the UK and I wanted to know if it's ok to mail both our (husband and mine) documents, along with our bio metrics information together to Visa Application Centre? Since, we are applying together for a tourist visa. Thanks so much!

Comment: as a couple, you are applying together,will be travelling together, staying on the same location within UK, so there should not be a problem.

Comment: @Nestsouls it's a great assumption, but it's not so much about travelling together and staying in the same location, rather it's about tracking and returning the applications.